# Textfield with autocomplete

Tags: oracle-apex

I have several fields that contain exactly the same sql query! Is it possible to place the sql question centrally in APEX in the same way as list of values or as a function in oracle? I am using APEX 18.2

Comment: I think you can use this plugin https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=64237:20:0: and use a list created on shared components

Comment: Thanks i will try it, hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally isolved it with a function and use the type PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query in APEX, then i have all in one place. I created a function in SQL developer that returns a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two extended solutions

Pipelined SQL
https://smart4solutions.nl/blog/on-apex-lovs-and-how-to-define-their-queries/

Dynamic SQL
http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/01/learn-to-hate-repetition-lesson-from.html

Comment: Sorry but it dosent work, a textfield with autocomplete dosent accept a two column query as used in lov's. I have tried with that but get error.

Comment: While you won't be able to define this as a declarative LOV, it will allow you to re-use a generic SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Call me dense**, but I don't think I understand why you'd have multiple fields (presumably on the same form) whose source is the same SQL query.

Are you passing a parameter to the SQL to get a different value for each field?

- **If you are** passing a parameter to the SQL query, why not create a database view to hold the query, then pass the parameter to the view. That way, if you need to change it, it's in one place.
- **If they really are all the same value** from the same query, how about using the SQL for one field/page_item, then make the source for the others be the first page item?

Comment: Use case - page with different fields representing different responsibilities, each choosing an app user from the shared LOV selecting from user table.

Comment: A "Textfield with autocomplete" must have a simple sql query like this: "select rtrim(username) from EBA_CA_USERS". This simple query is not accepted as a LOV and yes i have this query in a number of forms not multiple fields in the same form.

Comment: Yeah, I'm dense and didn't see that in your title!  :-(
Now I get it, you can't choose a LOV that's a Component because those require 2 columns, where the "Text w/ Autocomplete" only allows a single column.
If your concern is maintainability, I'd still define a view to point to your table, so even if you need to change it, it's only in the view.

Comment: I am working with database links and have several applications, every time i have a new release i have to update the same query in six places in each application :(. Thats the reason for my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a hidden item with the query in the source as text and use `&HIDDEN_ITEM_NAME.` to reference its value in the source of any item I was trying to display the query.

Comment: Thanks but sorry this dosent solve my problem, finally isolved it with a function and use the type PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query, then i have all in one place. I created a function in SQL developer that returns a SQL query.